# Задержка KeyStroke эвента

Tags: java

Есть такой код:

```
JButton b = new JButton("Hello");
KeyStroke k = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control 7");
InputMap i = b.getInputMap();
i.put(k, "keystroke");
ActionMap a = b.getActionMap();
a.put("keystroke", new AbstractAction(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        System.out.println("Pressed!");
    }
});
```

Вопрос следующий, когда нажимаю, но не отпускаю, мой action 1 раз срабатывает, ждет около 200 мс, и потом быстро вызывает actionPerformed.
Как сделать так, что бы задержки не было, нажал, задержал, сразу куча эвентов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, вопрос решен через костыль (как обычно =)). Модер может удалять пост если надо.